# Quiero que me inserte desde la segunda fila de mi excel y no desde la primera laravel

Tags: php, laravel, excel

Lo que quiero es que me inserte desde la segunda fila de mi excel ya que no quiero que me inserte el emcabezado de cada campo que coloco por ejemplo este es el encabezado que coloco PROVEEDOR,DESC_ENLACE y asi sucesivamente para que el usuario se guie de lo que esta colocando pero ala hora de insertar me inserta tambien el emcabezado y no se como podria resolver ese problema para indicarle al excel que me empieze a insertar desde la segunda fila no se como indicarle

Este es mi controlador

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Imports\Usersimport;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
//use Maatwebsite\Excel\Excel;
use App\importar;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class importarexcel extends Controller
{

    public function cargar_datos_usuarios(Request $request)
    {


        $file=$request->file('file');
        Excel::Import(new Usersimport,$file);

        return back()->with('message','Importacion de usuarios completado');


    }

}
```

Aqui llamo mi controlador el cual row me representa todas las filas de mi excel pero no se como indicarle que me empiece a insertar desde la segunda fila

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;

use App\importar;
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;



class Usersimport implements ToModel
{
    /**
     * @param array $row
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model|null
     */
    public function model(array $row)
    {
        return new importar([
            'PROVEEDOR' => $row[0],
            'DESC_ENLACE' => $row[1],
            'NO_FACTURA' => $row[2],
            'ID_ENLACE' => $row[3],
            'VALOR_PAGO' => $row[4],
            'PERIODO' => $row[5],
            'FECHA_FACTURA' => $row[6],
            'FECHA_INGRESO' => $row[7],
            'MONEDA' => $row[8],
            'TC_FACTURA' => $row[9],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Aqui corrigo como me dicen las instrucciones y esta es mi solucion del ejercicio dejo el link 
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html#heading-key-formatting

```
     <?php

namespace App\Imports;
namespace App\Imports;
use App\importar;
use App\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToModel;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Row;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Imports\HeadingRowFormatter;

HeadingRowFormatter::default('none');

class Usersimport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow
{


    public function model(array $row)
    {

        return new importar([
            'PROVEEDOR'  => $row['proveedor'],
            'DESC_ENLACE' => $row['desc_enlace'],
            'NO_FACTURA' => $row['no_factura'],
            'ID_ENLACE' => $row['id_enlace'],
            'VALOR_PAGO' => $row['valor_pago'],
            'PERIODO' => $row['periodo'],
            'FECHA_FACTURA' => $row['fecha_factura'],
            'FECHA_INGRESO' => $row['fecha_ingreso'],
            'MONEDA' => $row['moneda'],
            'TC_FACTURA' => $row['tc_factura'],
        ]);
    }

}
```

y este es mi modelo

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class importar extends Model
{
//    protected $table="`edavid.fcm_enl_ter_fact`";
    protected $table="edavid_fcm_enl_ter_fact";
//
    protected  $fillable  = [
        'PROVEEDOR','DESC_ENLACE','NO_FACTURA','ID_ENLACE','VALOR_PAGO','PERIODO','FECHA_FACTURA','FECHA_INGRESO','MONEDA','TC_FACTURA',
    ];
    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Haz uso de las siguientes instrucciones tal y como dice la [documentación](https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/heading-row.html)

```
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;


class Usersimport implements ToModel, WithHeadingRow {
  ....
}
```

Adicional nos dice que podemos hacer referencia al encabezado sin la necesidad de hacer uso del index del array numerico:

> We can now reference the heading instead of a numeric array key.

por lo tanto puedes hacer referencia al encabezado

```
'PROVEEDOR'  => $row['proveedor'],
```

Comment: si asi lo acabo de realizar ahi coloque como lo corregi pero ahora no me inserta me tira este error ErrorException 
Undefined index: PROVEEDOR

Comment: Voy a actualizar mi respuesta para agregarte más información.

Comment: Lo hice de esa forma los campos de mi hoja de ecxel los cambie a minusculas y las de mi base de datos estan en mayusculas pero me sigue tirando Undefined index: PROVEEDOR  cuando utilizo nombres con esa libreria use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow; ahi lo actulice como lo hice pero me tira este error

Comment: O ya lo resolvi tal y como me dijiste solo que tenia al reves los nombres en mayusculas ahi dejo la solucion

Comment: ¿Esta respuesta solucionó tu problema, @Juan Carlos Veliz? Por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada si tu problema fue resuelto. Puedes hacerlo marcando el ✓ en la parte izquierda de la respuesta (se pondrá verde, ganarás 2 puntos de reputación y podrías acceder a [nuevos privilegios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)). ¡Mira [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) si tienes alguna duda!

Comment: bueno resolvio mi problema ahorita lo resolvi el problema era que tenia en mayusculas las asignaciones en el for each pero no entiendo por que tendrian que estar en minusculas cuando en mi base estan todas en mayusculas